# watch() function not working angular.js on json call

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I want to execute a method when my $http.selectedSong (model value) changes , but I can't seem to let it work anny ideas how this comes?   :

```
app.controller('songController', ['$http', function($http) {

    $songs = this;
    $songs.tracks = [];

    $http({
            url: "http://api.q-music.be/1.2/tracks/plays?limit=20",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonp: "callback"
        })
        .success(function(lastSongsList) {

            $http.$watch('selectedSong', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                 if (newVal !== oldVal) {
                    alert('hej');
                 }
            });
        });

}]);
```

My goal is to work with data i achieved from this html code :

```
<select ng-model="selectedSong"  ng-init="selectedSong === songs.tracks[0].title" ng-options="song as song.title for song in songs.tracks"></select>
```

I want to see when the value I select in 'select' changes so i can work with this value to do methods etc ...

Comment: where is your selectedSong var defined ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? You aren't actually changing `selectedSong`. And `$http` doesn't have a `$watch` function. I suspect you want to do something when the HTTP request comes back? Then the success callback is all you need.

Comment: See my answer below. You can do this with `ng-change`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) is a construct that is unique to the [`$scope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) service.

I'm assuming you are using the `controller as` syntax in which case you are not directly using `$scope` within your controller. You can however, set up an [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive to execute arbitrary code whenever a bound model changes.

```
<select ng-model="ctrl.selectedSong" ng-change="ctrl.doStuff()">
```

This is ultimately a cleaner option than using a `$watch`

**Here is a working snippet based on your example above**

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  function InputController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.songs = ['Uptown Funk!', 'Thinking Out Loud','Take Me To Church','Blank Space'];
    vm.selectedSong = vm.songs[0];

    vm.onSongChange = function() {
      alert(vm.selectedSong);
    };
  }

  angular.module('inputs', [])
    .controller('InputCtrl', InputController);

}());
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.12/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="inputs" ng-controller="InputCtrl as ctrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h3>Primary</h3>
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="ctrl.selectedSong" ng-options="song for song in ctrl.songs" ng-change="ctrl.onSongChange()"></select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this ng-change thing is what i am looking for

Comment: so 'ctrl' is the name of the controller and 'doStuff() is a method defined in this controller?

Comment: @JimPeeters - I had assumed you were using the `controller as` syntax given your code snippet above was using `this` to bind properties to. If that's the case, then it is simply the alias you use when setting up your controller binding either via a directive `ng-controller="foo as ctrl"` or in your route, `{controller: 'foo', controllerAs: 'ctrl'}` **If you are not using controller as then simply disregard this**

Comment: i still have a question i know have in my html this :  
: <select ng-model="selectedSong" ng-change="songs.change()"  ng-options="song as song.title for song in songs.tracks"></select>

Comment: and in my javascript this :     app.controller('songController', ['$http', function($http) {

        $songs = this;
        $songs.tracks = [];

        $http({
                url: "http://api.q-music.be/1.2/tracks/plays?limit=20",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                jsonp: "callback"
            })
            .success(function(lastSongsList) {
                $songs.tracks = lastSongsList.played_tracks;
                console.log($songs.tracks);
            
            });
        
        function change(){
            alert('test');
        }
        
    }]);

Comment: but the change method doesn't seem to do a thing

Comment: To make it clear , where and how in my controller should i define the change method

Comment: @JimPeeters - I've included a snippet to make things more clear.

Answer (score 0):

you catn watch `$http` it service not `$scope`

you can only watch $scope property

here is a link to [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)